# How to write code in html for retrieving the session value.?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a Default2.cs file which stores a value in session

```
TextBox1.Text = "Haii";
    Session["name"] = TextBox1.Text;
```

and i need to retrieve it in an html page- Default.aspx

```
   <script runat="server">
Sub Page_Load

  string na=(string)Session["name"];
  Label1.Text=na;
End Sub
</script>
```

it shows an error 'String' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression.
please help

Comment: Are you using C# or VB.net?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in HTML in Defaul.aspx,

```
    <% string na=(string)Session["name"]; %>
    <label id="Label1"><% =na %></label>
```

Comment: <% string na=(string)Session["name"]; %>
<%Label1.Text=na;%> When writing like this it shows "Character is not valid"

Comment: If the error code is BC30037 then its a VS bug. There are many solutions online, like renaming .aspx to asp.. debugging it.. then renaming it again back to .aspx. It works for most of them.

Comment: when try to renaming Default.aspx to .asp ,it shows a message "if u change a file name it become un usable"

Comment: Its ok. Once you change it back it will be OK. Check this link out. http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/325996-character-not-valid

Answer (score 0):

**For ASPX Engine:**

Enclose your code in `<% Your Code here %>`

```
<% string na=(string)Session["name"]; %>
```

**For Razor Engine:**

Enclose your code in `@{ Your Code here }`

```
@{ 
    string na=(string)Session["name"];
}
```

Comment: <% string na=(string)Session["name"]; %>
<%Label1.Text=na;%> shows an error "Character not valid "

Comment: @DIVYAHARI For which character?

Comment: <% string na=(string)Session["name"]; %>